# Why is xlsread returning empty?

Tags: excel, matlab, file-io, xlsread

I'm trying to read some data stored in a .xlsx file into MATLAB. However, using xlsread returns an empty data set.

```
data = xlsread('myFile.xlsx');
```

The sheet name is the standard 'Sheet1', so I know it's not looking for the wrong sheet.

I even checked to make sure the file exists, and went as far as to use uigetfile to ensure the path and string names are correct:

```
[fileName,dirName]=uigetfile('.xlsx');
data = xlsread(fullfile(dirName,fileName));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`xlsread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) only returns numeric data when only one output is specified. If the .xlsx file contains only text data, it will return empty. To remedy this, specify the outputs:

```
[fileName,dirName]=uigetfile('.xlsx');
[~,~,rawData] = xlsread(fullfile(dirName,fileName));
```

will return the entire contents of the sheet without MATLAB parsing the results and deciding what's text and what's numeric data.

Comment: you might also be interested in this: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/xlsread-functionality-change-in-r2012a/

Comment: @Amro: Good tip. I thought I'd post this Q&A for anyone else experiencing the same brain lapse that cost me 15 minutes of very frustrated troubleshooting.